# Virtual Machine Manager Error - Error determing default hypervisor

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora, xen

I have Fedora 11 and trying to get Xen working (which I think it is already) but the Virtual Machine Manager cannot find the hypervisor.

When starting Virtual Machine Manager, I receive the following error

Error determining default hypervisor.  Could not populate a default connection.  Make sure the appropriate virtualization packages are installed (kvm, qemu, etc.) and that libvirtd has been restarted to notice the change.  A hypervisor connection can be manually added via File -> Add Connection

I've restarted libvirtd a few times and tried connecting manually but can't work it out.

Some useful information:

```
# lsof | grep xen
libvirtd 2962 root mem REG 253,0 19776 13379 /usr/lib/libxenstore.so.3.0.0

# service libvirtd status
libvirtd (pid  2962) is running...
```

Answer (score 0):

after looking into the issue a bit, I found xen isn't really supported after Fedora v8

instead I've got QEMU working, took 10 seconds to install